# how to auto sum multiple inputbox inner loop in javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I want to calculate my input box inner looping and this bellow is what if done please help me to solve this issue

```
<?php
$jumlah_form = 3;
    for($i=1; $i<=$jumlah_form; $i++){
    ?>
    <input type="text" id="txt1"  onkeyup="sum1();" /></br>

    <?php
    }
    ?>
    <input type="text" id="txt2" value= "0" /></br>
   <script>
  function sum1() {
      var txtFirstNumberValue = document.getElementById('txt1').value;
      var txtSecondNumberValue = document.getElementById('txt2').value;
      var result = parseInt(txtFirstNumberValue) + parseInt(txtFirstNumberValue) ;
      if (!isNaN(result)) {
         document.getElementById('txt2').value = result;
      }
   }
  </script>
```

[image]

Three input boxes are created by looping, I want to calculate three input box, and parse the result into result box whenever user input number

Comment: Is there an error in your code? Which `<input>` should give the function?

Comment: i have no found error, if u think that how it should be wrote?

Comment: I like to see errors in blockquotes. Your question is also hard to understand... Can you proofread it, please?

Comment: @Rojo I have edit my question still u not understand what I mean.. if u think my code was wrong and get in error,, please give me suggest what I have to write suppose

Comment: What you are saying in your question makes no sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are asking how to write the JavaScript so that it will add up the total of all the input boxes, no matter how many are created by the PHP?

If so then a good way would be to give all the textboxes the same class. Then, the JavaScript can just select all boxes with that class, loop through them and get the total value.

Here's a worked example using 3 textboxes (as if the PHP had generated them this way):

```js
var textboxes = document.querySelectorAll(".sum");
textboxes.forEach(function(box) {
  box.addEventListener("keyup", sumAll);
});

function sumAll() {
  var total = 0;
  textboxes.forEach(function(box) {
    var val;
    if (box.value == "") val = 0;
    else val = parseInt(box.value);
    total += val;
  });
  document.getElementById("total").innerText = total;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="txt1" class="sum" value="0" /><br/>
<input type="number" id="txt2" class="sum" value="0" /><br/>
<input type="number" id="txt3" class="sum" value="0" /><br/>
<br/><br/> Total: <span id="total"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

To generate html with php:

```
$count = 5;

for($i=1;$i <= $count;$i++) {

  echo "<input type='number' id='"."txt".i."' /></br>"

}
```

To calculate sum from inputs:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form onsubmit="submitForm(this); return false;" >
    <input type="number" id='text1'>
    <input type="number" id='text2'>
    <input type="number" id='text3'>
    <input type="number" id='text4'>
    <input type="number" id='text5'>
    <button type="submit" >Calculate</button>
  </form>
  <div>
    <p>Result:</p>
    <p id='result'></p>
  </div>
  
  <script>
   function submitForm(form) {
     let toReturn = 0;
     const inputs = form.getElementsByTagName("input");
      for(let x = 0; x < inputs.length; x++ ) {
        toReturn += parseInt(inputs[x].value ? inputs[x].value : 0);
      }
      
      document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = toReturn;
      return false;
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```